# How to add ViewController to UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I got a UIPageViewController on my storyboard, and now I'm wondering how do I add a view controller to it? Lets say if I got 5 view controllers, how do I add those from the beginning to the end to the UIPageViewController? Normally I would do this:

```
        [self addChildViewController:firstViewController];
        [self addChildViewController:secondViewController];
        [self addChildViewController:thridViewController];
        [self addChildViewController:fourthViewController];
        [self addChildViewController:fifthViewController];
```

But I'm not sure how to add this on the UIPageViewController in this order...

**EDIT:**

```
ChapterViewController *chapterViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChapterView"];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:chapterViewController];

[self setViewControllers:viewControllers
                         direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                          animated:NO
              completion:^(BOOL finished){
                  NSLog(@"call back success");}];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIPageViewController doesn't allow an easy way to add new view controllers one at a time, presumably because Apple wants developers to ***not*** add pages one at a time very easily (I could see this being confusing UI for users of an app).

To do what you want to do, you have to add the new view controller to an array (presumably the array of already existing view controllers, which you retrieve via ["`viewControllers`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPageViewController/viewControllers)) and then call ["`setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPageViewController/setViewControllers%3adirection%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a) with the **new** array of view controllers including your one (or more) new view controllers to be added to the Page View Controller.

Comment: Please check my edited answer, I've tried this but it just shows me a black screen.. ( I've put the code in the viewDidLoad from the UIPageViewController class)

Comment: However the "call back succes" does get printed out

Comment: the reason that is happening is because your page view controller is confused about *what* to display. It was displaying some other view controller when you called this code, but then you're deleting **all view controllers** and replacing it with only your ChapterViewController, which I suspect is not what you really wanted to do.  You need to add your ChapterViewController to the end of all the other view controllers.

Comment: set breakpoints in your ChapterViewController and see if "`viewDidLoad`" gets called.  Also what happens when you set "`animated`" parameter to "`YES`"?

Comment: The viewDidLoad from Chapter does get called, and still the same result when setting the parameter to "YES"

Comment: I've just tried it with another UIViewController and this works fine, however what if I want to add another viewcontroller to the NSArray viewController property just after the one I added before?

Comment: why don't you come [chat with me on chat.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad) instead of us hashing this out in a huge comment thread